# How to use ReactiveCocoa with Gesture Recognizers

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm building an application using ReactiveCocoa. The top view is a menu which can be pulled down then pushed back up. I have to use two different gesture recognizers – one for pulling down and one for pushing back up. Only one can be enabled at a time – and there's my problem. State.

I'm using the BlocksKit extension to set up the gesture recognizer.

```
self.panHeaderDownGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithHandler:^(UIGestureRecognizer *sender, UIGestureRecognizerState state, CGPoint location) {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender;

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        [self.downwardHeaderPanSubject sendNext:@(translation.y)];
    }
    else if (state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // Determine the direction the finger is moving and ensure if it was moving down, that it exceeds the minimum threshold for opening the menu.
        BOOL movingDown = ([recognizer velocityInView:self.view].y > 0 && translation.y > kMoveDownThreshold);

        // Animate the change
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
            if (movingDown)
            {
                [self.downwardHeaderPanSubject sendNext:@(kMaximumHeaderTranslationThreshold)];
            }
            else
            {
                [self.downwardHeaderPanSubject sendNext:@(0)];
            }
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self.menuFinishedTransitionSubject sendNext:@(movingDown)];
        }];
    }
}];
```

In my `initWithNibName:bundle:` method, I'm setting up the following `RACSubject`s.

```
self.headerMovementSubject = [RACSubject subject];
[self.headerMovementSubject subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    @strongify(self);

    // This is the ratio of the movement. 0 is closed and 1 is open.
    // Values less than zero are treated as zero.
    // Values greater than one are valid and will be extrapolated beyond the fully open menu.
    CGFloat ratio = [x floatValue];

    CGRect headerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), kHeaderHeight + ratio * kMaximumHeaderTranslationThreshold);

    if (ratio < 0)
    {            
        headerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), kHeaderHeight);
    }

    self.headerViewController.view.frame = headerFrame;
}];

// This subject is responsible for receiving translations from a gesture recognizers and turning
// thos values into ratios. These ratios are fead into other signals.
self.downwardHeaderPanSubject = [RACSubject subject];
[self.downwardHeaderPanSubject subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *translation) {
    @strongify(self);
    CGFloat verticalTranslation = [translation floatValue];

    CGFloat effectiveRatio = 0.0f;

    if (verticalTranslation <= 0)
    {
        effectiveRatio = 0.0f;
    }
    else if (verticalTranslation <= kMaximumHeaderTranslationThreshold)
    {
        effectiveRatio = fabsf(verticalTranslation / kMaximumHeaderTranslationThreshold);
    }
    else
    {
        CGFloat overshoot = verticalTranslation - kMaximumHeaderTranslationThreshold;
        CGFloat y = 2 * sqrtf(overshoot + 1) - 2;
        effectiveRatio = 1.0f + (y / kMaximumHeaderTranslationThreshold);
    }

    [self.headerMovementSubject sendNext:@(effectiveRatio)];
}];

// This subject is responsible for mapping this value to other signals and state (ugh). 
self.menuFinishedTransitionSubject = [RACReplaySubject subject];
[self.menuFinishedTransitionSubject subscribeNext:^(NSNumber *menuIsOpenNumber) {
    @strongify(self);

    BOOL menuIsOpen = menuIsOpenNumber.boolValue;

    self.panHeaderDownGestureRecognizer.enabled = !menuIsOpen;
    self.panHeaderUpGestureRecognizer.enabled = menuIsOpen;
    self.otherViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = !menuIsOpen;

    if (menuIsOpen)
    {
        [self.headerViewController flashScrollBars];
    }
}];
```

There's a lot going on here. The problem is exacerbated by the fact that I've got nearly double the number of subjects as I've listed here (ones for the pan-up gesture recognizer, too), *plus* another set of recognizers for similar interaction with the footer. That's a lot of subjects.

My question is in two parts:

1. Is there a better way to set up the kind of chaining I want? I'm re-using some of the subjects in my push-up gesture, as well, which looks really similar. I've got a lot of `RACSubjects` and it seems janky.
2. The `menuFinishedTransitionSubject` is essentially used for managing the state of the gesture recognizers. I tried binding their `enabled` property without any luck. Any advice here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's focus on the explicit subscriptions, because those are generally the low-hanging fruit for rewriting imperative code.

First of all, based on the code shown, it looks like `headerMovementSubject` is only fed values from `downwardHeaderPanSubject` (and nowhere else). That's an easy candidate for writing as a transformation instead:

```
RACSignal *headerFrameSignal = [[self.downwardHeaderPanSubject
    map:^(NSNumber *translation) {
        CGFloat verticalTranslation = [translation floatValue];
        CGFloat effectiveRatio = 0.0f;

        // Calculate effectiveRatio.

        return @(effectiveRatio);
    }]
    map:^(NSNumber *effectiveRatio) {
        // Calculate headerFrame.

        return @(headerFrame);
    }];
```

Then, instead of manipulating `self.headerViewController.view.frame` as a side effect, we can use a binding:

```
RAC(self.headerViewController.view.frame) = headerFrameSignal;
```

We can do similar things with the booleans in `menuFinishedTransitionSubject`:

```
RAC(self.panHeaderDownGestureRecognizer.enabled) = [self.menuFinishedTransitionSubject not];
RAC(self.panHeaderUpGestureRecognizer.enabled) = self.menuFinishedTransitionSubject;
RAC(self.otherViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled) = [self.menuFinishedTransitionSubject not];
```

Unfortunately, `-flashScrollBars` still needs to be invoked as a side effect, but we can at least lift the filtering out of the block:

```
[[self.menuFinishedTransitionSubject
    filter:^(NSNumber *menuIsOpen) {
        return menuIsOpen.boolValue;
    }]
    subscribeNext:^(id _) {
        @strongify(self);

        [self.headerViewController flashScrollBars];
    }];
```

If you want to get really fancy, a lot of the gesture recognizer logic can be represented with stream transformations instead, and the animation could be implemented with [ReactiveCocoaLayout](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoaLayout/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaLayout/RACSignal%2BRCLAnimationAdditions.h), but that's a rewrite of its own.

Comment: If `headerMovementSubject` was being fed from the move-up gesture recognizer (and corresponding signals), how would that work? Would I still need the explicit subject property?

Comment: Subjects are often a code smell, since they're basically mutable variables. Instead, I would focus on combining the move-down and move-up gesture recognizer subjects (e.g., using `+combineLatest:`) into something which can feed into the transformations above.